# How to read data from DapperRow?

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api2, dapper

I am using Dapper version="2.0.78" for .NETFramework = 4.7.2 based asp.net web api2 application.

Here goes my Response object:

***SampleResponse.cs***

```
public class SampleResponse
{
    public SampleResponse()
    {
        Test1 = new List<A>();
        Test2 = new List<A>();
        Test3 = new List<A>();
    }

    public bool IsValueReady
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public List<A> Test1
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public List<A> Test2
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public List<A> Test3
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
}

public async Task<SampleResponse> GetDataAsync(RequestDTO value)
{
    SampleResponse response = null;
    using (var conn = await _dapperService.CreateConnection())
    {
        var data = await conn.QueryMultipleAsync("stp_FetchData", commandType: CommandType.StoredProcedure);
        var response1 = await data.ReadAsync();
        var response2 = await data.ReadAsync<A>();
        var response3 = await data.ReadAsync<A>();
        var response4 = await data.ReadAsync<A>();
        response = new SampleResponse{IsValueReady = response1.FirstOrDefault(), Test1 = response2.ToList(), Test2 = response3.ToList(), Test3 = response3.ToList()};
    }

    return response;
}
```

**stp_FetchData:**

```
SELECT @pI_BIsValueReady AS IsValueReady
SELECT * FROM #Table1;
SELECT * FROM #Table2;
SELECT * FROM #Table3;
```

On debugging the below line

var response1 = await data.ReadAsync();

gives me the following response and I want to read the value of IsValueReady from it

```
{{DapperRow, IsValueReady = 'True'}}
```

I want to extract the value of IsValueReady in this case.

Can anyone help me here by providing their guidance to fix this issue?

Comment: Have you tried `response1.IsValueReady`? or `response1.FirstOrDefault?.IsValueReady ?? false`.  I'm pretty sure that a Dapper query that doesn't have a type specified returns an `IEnumerable<dynamic>`

Comment: Thanks @Flydog57 for your response. Yes you are correct the return type is IEnumerable<dynamic>. Can you please help me some code sample regarding how to read the value in this case. Any help on this is much appreciated

Comment: Well, calling `FirstOrDefault` on an `IEnumerable<T>` will give you a `T` or, if the collection is empty, the default value, in this case `null`. So, at that point, you'll have either `null` or a `dynamic`. Since you know the property name you're interested in, you can get it: `response1.FirstOrDefault()?.IsValueReady??false` should do it. The FirstOrDefault call will return null or a dynamic. The `?.` will call IsValueReady if the result is non-null. If it is null, it will make the entire expression null. The `??` says return the value, but if it's null, return `false`

Comment: How about If I have {{DapperRow, IsValueReady = 'True',AnotherValue = "abc"}}.

Comment: Read up on how `dynamic` works

Comment: Sure @Flydog57. Thanks again for your response :)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks much @Flydog57. I did some reading on dynamic type and was able to resolve the issue with the following code snippet:

```
public async Task<SampleResponse> GetDataAsync(RequestDTO value)
{
    SampleResponse response = null;
    using (var conn = await _dapperService.CreateConnection())
    {
        var data = await conn.QueryMultipleAsync("stp_FetchData", commandType: CommandType.StoredProcedure);
        var response1 = await data.ReadAsync();
        var response2 = await data.ReadAsync<A>();
        var response3 = await data.ReadAsync<A>();
        var response4 = await data.ReadAsync<A>();
        
        var tempData = response1.FirstOrDefault();
        
        
        
        response = new SampleResponse{IsValueReady = tempData.IsValueReady, Test1 = response2.ToList(), Test2 = response3.ToList(), Test3 = response3.ToList()};
    }

    return response;
}
```